# Javascript - click link in iframe

Tags: javascript

I was able to grab a link from my iframe from the parent. They are on the same domain.

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('ifr1');
doc = iframe.contentDocument;
doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[10].href
```

How can I click on that link from the parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JavaScript:

```
doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[10].click();
```

Or

```
window.location.href = doc.getElementsByTagName('a')[10];
```

Or you can invoke any links with JQuery this way:

```
$("#ifr1 a:eq(10)").click();
```

Comment: Thanks. What does the a:eq mean on the jquery one?

Comment: a mean to search for link and :eq to get the element number 10 (the number is set between parentheses)

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if its possible, but I would read the href and set it as the location.path