# How to detect a link click with JavaScript/jQuery in a iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

How can I detect a link click inside a iFrame?

The Frame source changes a lot of times and I need to detect all link click inside the iFrame.

I try that already: [Javascript - click link in iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372533/javascript-click-link-in-iframe)

JS:

```
$("#Source a").click();
```

HTML:

```
<iframe src="" name="Source" id="Source" scrolling="" frameborder="0" title="Anzeigebereich"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use .contents() http://api.jquery.com/contents/

```
$('#Source').on('load', function(){
    $(this).contents().find('body').on('click', 'a', function(e){
        e.preventDefault(e);//stop normal navigation
        //your code here
    });
});
```

Comment: this work only on iframe hosted on the same web domain

Answer (score 0):

If you trying to catch an event or do whatever inside the iframe from the oustide document, it isn't possible, the iframe is different context (different document) and this is not alowed. You can check a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381336/detect-click-into-iframe-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

use post message, for communicaton between frames, also support different domains

[post message doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)